# How to restructure the JSON Object with new key values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Please help me to recreate the JSON object received from API, refer below JSON object from API
**below is Input JSON**

```
{
  'Demo-1': [
    {
      sku: 'Brisk',
      count: '2',
    },
    {
      sku: 'Pepsi Cans',
      count: '2',
    },
    {
      sku: 'Pepsi Cans',
      count: '4',
    }
    
  ],
  
  'Demo-2' : [
    {
      sku: 'Mountain',
      count: '4',
    },
    {
      sku: 'Pepsi Bottles',
      count: '4',
    },
    {
      sku: 'Lipton Dietgreentea',
      count: '2',
    },
    {
      sku: 'Lipton Dietgreentea Mixedberry',
      count: '2',
    }
  ]
}
```

from this to convert below JSON object with additional keys, and restructure the array items inside the another key

**Result should be like**

```
{
    'Demo-1': {
        items: [{
                sku: 'Brisk',
                count: '2',
            },
            {
                sku: 'Pepsi',
                count: '2',
            },
            {
                sku: 'Pepsi',
                count: '4',
            }

        ],
        mode: "Veri",
        status: "open"

    },
    'Demo-2': {
        "items": [{
                sku: 'Mountain',
                count: '4',
            },
            {
                sku: 'Pepsi Bottles',
                count: '4',
            },
            {
                sku: 'Lipton Dietgreentea',
                count: '2',
            },
            {
                sku: 'Lipton Dietgreentea Mixedberry',
                count: '2',
            }
        ],
        mode: "Clear",
        status: "Closed"
    }
}
```

I tried in angular but I cant achieve the result, please look out the code below

```
 Object.entries(_data).map((items,idx)=>{
     
      this._newPickLists = {
        items[0] :{
          items : items[1],
          mode : 'Verification',
          status : 'open'
        }
      }

    
    })
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can your provide a code snippet. There is stuff like `this` which do not make sense and we cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: it's just a declaration in angular _newPickLists: any;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Object.entries` and `Object.fromEntries`, you can just change the value to the object with items as the key

```js
const obj = {"Demo-1":[{"sku":"Brisk","count":"2"},{"sku":"Pepsi Cans","count":"2"},{"sku":"Pepsi Cans","count":"4"}],"Demo-2":[{"sku":"Mountain","count":"4"},{"sku":"Pepsi Bottles","count":"4"},{"sku":"Lipton Dietgreentea","count":"2"},{"sku":"Lipton Dietgreentea Mixedberry","count":"2"}]};

console.log(
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).map(
      ([key, items]) => [key, { items, mode: "verification", status: "open" }]
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `newObject` with the variable in your app.

```
const newObject = {};

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
    newObject[key] = {};
    newObject[key]["items"] = value;
    newObject[key].mode = "Clear";
    newObject[key].status = "Closed";

}

console.log(newObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that will update the original data object:

```
  Object.keys(data).forEach((key)=> { 
     data[key] = {items: data[key], mode: 'Veri', status: 'open' }}
  )
```